# Case Statement for Each Group

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, case, cross-apply

Thank you for looking.  I am trying to derive new columns from my existing data based on CASE statements, and I can't seem to get it to work.

I have available to me IncidentID, SPECCOLLECTEDDATE and a derived column I've already set up successfully called PN.PositiveNegative, which indicates whether a test is positive or negative.

Here's what I want to do.  IncidentID has many instances of duplicates, and in this instance that means that for one IncidentID, at least one, but sometimes more than one, test exists.  For each grouping of IncidentIDs, I want to find:

DateFirstPositive (required), the earliest positive test date
DateLastPositive (optional, the most recent positive test date
DateFirstNegative (optional), the earliest negative test date
DateLastNegative (optional), the most recent negative date

I have been trying to get CASE statements to work with this, but I can't seem to get it.  The main block I'm struggling with is how to apply the CASE statement to GROUPs of IncidentIDs within a CROSS APPLY expression.

Any help you could offer would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Some sample data, expected output and the code you tried would be very helpful

Comment: FYI its a `case` expression *not* statement.

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select IncidentID,
       min(case when value > 0 then SPECCOLLECTEDDATE end) as first_positive_date,
       max(case when value > 0 then SPECCOLLECTEDDATE end) as last_positive_date,
       min(case when value < 0 then SPECCOLLECTEDDATE end) as first_negative_date,
       max(case when value < 0 then SPECCOLLECTEDDATE end) as last_negative_date
from t
group by IncidentID;
```